# Are there any general tithis considered auspicious for buying any materialistic item?

Tags: muhurta, tithi

My friend says krishna paksha is not desirable to buy a new item like a phone or car or laptop. Rather shukla paksha is better.

Further, new moon is to be avoided as friend say.

Is this true as per scripture?

Is shukla paksha days better to buy?

Also is first day (prathma) of any paksha ill suited for buying?

What days (Friday, Wednesday, etc) or tithis (dwitiya, tritiya, etc) of which paksha are considered best and which one worst for buying materialistic items?
Plz tell per scriptures.